# Aggregate an attribute hierarchy in SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: mdx, tabular, ssas-2012

I have created a tabular model using SSAS 2012 and i'm having an attribute hierarchy called "Date" (yyyy-MM-01T00:00:00 format) with 12000 records in it. I found a built-in function "Aggregate" to aggregate the user-defined hierarchies in Multidimensional model. Now, my question is how to aggregate my "Date" hierarchy per year with MDX?

Comment: Aggregate can mean more than just 'sum' (and you can't sum all those dates!). You can use a MIN or MAX or AVG calculation for the aggregation.